# Estimating VECM with Exogenous variable

Tags: vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model, impulse-response

I'm currently working on a project that requires estimating a Vector Error Correction Model (VECM), potentially extending to a structural VECM, that incorporates at least one exogenous variable. The primary objective is to analyze the dynamic responses of two commodity prices to shocks in an exogenous variable, particularly focusing on tracing out impulse response functions and computing standard error bands for these responses.

My questions are:

1. Are you aware of any existing packages or libraries that support the estimation of a VECM or structural VECM with an exogenous variable in R?
2. If you have experience with such analyses, could you please share any tips on the best practices or potential pitfalls in conducting this type of analysis? Any advice on troubleshooting the mentioned error or on the overall approach to modeling these relationships would be incredibly valuable.

Comment: You might try the urca package or the tsDyn package (VECM).